# Spring Date JPA java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EntityPathResolver must not be null!

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Ответьте пожалуйста, почему возникает такая ошибка и как ее исправить?!! Прошерстил весь интернет, но не смог найти(

Stack trace ошибки:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addressRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EntityPathResolver must not be null!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:830)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
at by.babanin.App.main(App.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.uiDesigner.snapShooter.SnapShooter.main(SnapShooter.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EntityPathResolver must not be null!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.setEntityPathResolver(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:111)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.createRepositoryFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:105)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.doCreateRepositoryFactory(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:96)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.createRepositoryFactory(TransactionalRepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:80)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:270)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
... 17 more
```

Файл App.java:

```
package by.babanin;

import by.babanin.entity.Address;
import by.babanin.entity.Employee;
import by.babanin.entity.Project;
import by.babanin.repository.AddressRepository;
import by.babanin.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import by.babanin.repository.ProjectRepository;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        AddressRepository addressRepository = context.getBean(AddressRepository.class);
        EmployeeRepository employeeRepository = context.getBean(EmployeeRepository.class);
        ProjectRepository projectRepository = context.getBean(ProjectRepository.class);

        Address address = new Address();
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        Project project = new Project();
        setExample(address, employee, project);
        System.out.println(address);
        System.out.println(employee);
        System.out.println(project);

        addressRepository.save(address);
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
        projectRepository.save(project);

        System.out.println(addressRepository.findAll());

        System.out.println(employeeRepository.findByFirstNameAndLastName("Dmitry", "Babanin"));
    }

    public static void setExample(Address address, Employee employee, Project project) {
        address.setCountry("Belarus");
        address.setCity("Minsk");
        address.setStreet("per. Kalinina 7/49");
        address.setPostCode("220012");

        employee.setFirstName("Dmitry");
        employee.setLastName("Babanin");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(1996, Calendar.APRIL, 21);
        employee.setBirthday(new Date(calendar.getTime().getTime()));
        employee.setAddress(address);

        project.setTitle("Искуственный интелект");

        Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
        employees.add(employee);
        project.setEmployees(employees);

        Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
        projects.add(project);
        employee.setProjects(projects);
    }
}
```

Файл AddressRepository.java:

```
package by.babanin.repository;

import by.babanin.entity.Address;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {}
```

Файл applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
    <jpa:repositories base-package="by.babanin.repository"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaData"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Файл persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="jpaData"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"/>
</persistence>
```

[image: Архитектура программы]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459543/error-when-creating-jpa-repository-entitypathresolver-must-not-be-null

Comment: Ошибка исправлена, но появилась новая

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В applicationContext.xml добавил следующие строки:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="by.babanin.repository">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
    </context:component-scan>
```

Ошибка исчезла, но появилась новая:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: by.babanin.entity.Address; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: by.babanin.entity.Address
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:317)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.save(Unknown Source)
    at by.babanin.App.main(App.java:35)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: by.babanin.entity.Address
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:828)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:795)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:428)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:804)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:308)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:489)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 10 more
```

Выполнились следующие команды:

```
Hibernate: drop table ADDRESS if exists
Hibernate: drop table EMPL_PROJ if exists
Hibernate: drop table EMPLOYEE if exists
Hibernate: drop table PROJECT if exists
Hibernate: create table ADDRESS (id bigint generated by default as identity, CITY varchar(255), COUNTRY varchar(255), POST_CODE varchar(10), STREET varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table EMPL_PROJ (EMPLOYEE_ID bigint not null, PROJECT_ID bigint not null, primary key (EMPLOYEE_ID, PROJECT_ID))
Hibernate: create table EMPLOYEE (id bigint generated by default as identity, BIRTHDAY date, FIRST_NAME varchar(255), LAST_NAME varchar(255), address_id bigint, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table PROJECT (id bigint generated by default as identity, TITLE varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table EMPL_PROJ add constraint FKf4n2q2crw04gao7chxtod454x foreign key (PROJECT_ID) references PROJECT
Hibernate: alter table EMPL_PROJ add constraint FKav7fscw3tnwn6d69xyjm8v87r foreign key (EMPLOYEE_ID) references EMPLOYEE
Hibernate: alter table EMPLOYEE add constraint FKl1e6165d2k04n8y71egbt8txu foreign key (address_id) references ADDRESS
Hibernate: insert into ADDRESS (id, CITY, COUNTRY, POST_CODE, STREET) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```